# Issue creating WebSocket Connection via Mosquitto broker

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

Mosquitto broker version 1.5.9

WebSocket support enabled and built

Port 9001 is opened on the broker

OS Amazon Linux 2 AMI (Fedora)

mosquitto_conf

```
port 1883

listener 9001
protocol websockets

==========================================================

1592388049: mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf 
1592388049: mosquitto version 1.5.9 starting 
1592388049: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf. 
1592388049: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1592388049: |-- ** Configured order: mysql
1592388049: |-- }}}} MYSQL 
1592388049: |-- SSL is disabled 
1592388049: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001. 
1592388049: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
1592388049: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

However when I try to connect to the broker via websocket using a simple Paho Javascript program, I get the following error:

> mqttws31.js:977 WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x:9001/mqtt'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> Connection failed: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out.Retrying

Comment: Have you opened all the ports in the AWS firewall?

Comment: Yes I added the inbound rule and rebooted the server.

Comment: Both the firewall on the machine (firewalld) and in the AWS console?

Comment: Just added a rule using firewalld for port 9001

Comment: If that works I'll add it as a real answer so you can accept it.

Comment: sorry that comment was incomplete, Connection failed: AMQJS0008I Socket closed.Retrying is the new error just googling now to try and find solution

Comment: Check the other end of the connection (look at the mosquitto logs for errors)

Comment: @hardillb thanks for help. I couldn't find a solution to this issue, so I decided to try and rebuild on a ubuntu instance.. as I am more familiar with that.